# Can't run any serverless commands without error

Tags: linux, npm

Not sure if I've tagged this question correctly, but...

I installed the [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/) and went through a tutorial to deploy an app. All good. Then I changed into my actual project's directory and tried to do the same. I got some error. I fiddled around and now I'm at the point where I literally cannot run a command of the form `serverless ...` without seeing this error:

```
  Error: {"errorMessage":"You're not authorized to access this resource. - Please contact support and provide this identifier to reference this issue - GW23VXDFFZXT"}
      at _callee$ (/home/josh/new-website/node_modules/@serverless/platform-sdk/src/utils/checkHttpResponse.js:19:9)
      at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:22)
      at Generator.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:118:21)
      at step (/home/josh/new-website/node_modules/@serverless/platform-sdk/dist/utils/checkHttpResponse.js:7:191)
      at /home/josh/new-website/node_modules/@serverless/platform-sdk/dist/utils/checkHttpResponse.js:7:361
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Here is my environment information:

```
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              12.19.0
     Framework Version:         2.15.0
     Plugin Version:            4.3.0
     SDK Version:               2.3.2
     Components Version:        3.4.3
```

I've tried:

- logging out and logging back into serverless ❌
- uninstalling and reinstalling serverless ❌

Even running `serverless -v` presents me with this error. Any ideas? Thank you!

**EDIT**: Not sure what the solution was, but I logged out of serverless, created a new account on the website, logged into serverless with that account, and updated the org field in my serverless.yml. It worked after that. Thanks for the answers and comments!

Comment: https://forum.serverless.com/t/youre-not-authorized-to-access-this-resource/11923 suggests "I switched devices (from home PC to work PC) and I was not logged in SLS on that device. Perhaps you need to sls login with your credentials first?" I find the "Please contact support and provide this identifier to reference this issue - GW23VXDFFZXT" very specific; is there a support vendor involved here?

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that the org name reflected in your `serverless.yml` file under the `org` property matches the name of the organization you created on `app.serverless.com`. If it doesn't, please rename the `org` property in your `serverless.yml` file to match.

Comment: This was the case but I resolved that issue and was still presented with the error. I've resolved it now, but I'm not sure what the solution was.

Comment: I develop this product, and examined the logs on our end to find the initial mismatch where you were attempting to access an org to which you did not belong/own.

Looking now, I see that there are several attempts to access an org "undefined". If you removed the value, but still left the `org` key in your `serverless.yml` file, you may have encountered this.

In the future, feel free to reach out to support via live chat inside the dashboard. Thanks!